# Однородные члены предложения, соединенные повторяющимися союзами

Tags: пунктуация

> И нагнулся старый атаман и стал отыскивать свою люльку с табаком,
>   неотлучную сопутницу на морях и на суше, и в походах и дома. (Н.В. Гоголь)

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему перед союзом стоит запятая? Ведь в данном случае он соединяет пары однородных членов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 9. Если союз и соединяет однородные члены предложения попарно, то запятая
>      ставится только между парами, а внутри них не ставится. Парные группы
>      однородных членов, в свою очередь, могут соединяться повторяющимся
>      союзом.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=124#pp124

Далее у Розенталя следует ваш пример из Гоголя. Можно заключить, что наличие союза "и" между парами (здесь имеет место объединение в пары противопоставлений) не отменяет запятой, место которой определено в первой части правила.

Comment: То есть здесь первый союз "и" опускается? Но ведь в пятом пункте у Розенталя  говорится, что "если число однородных членов больше двух, а союз повторяется перед каждым из них, кроме первого, то запятая ставится между ними всеми, например: А вокруг были дым, и бой, и смерть (Горбатов); Иные хозяева вырастили уже вишни, или сирень, или жасмин (Фадеев); Только мальвы, да ноготки, да крученый паныч цвели кое-где по дорогам (В. Панова)".

Comment: Это про другое, смотрите пункт 9 о попарном соединении членов союзом "и".

Comment: И нагнулся старый атаман и стал отыскивать свою люльку с табаком, неотлучную сопутницу на морях и на суше, и в походах и дома. (Н.В. Гоголь)

Comment: В пункте 9 сказано, что союз повторяющийся, а в предложении "и нагнулся старый атаман и стал отыскивать свою люльку с табаком, неотлучную сопутницу на морях и на суше, и в походах и дома" его нет. Там только перед словом "в походах", а для постановки запятой должен стоять ещё перед "на морях".

Comment: Вопрос был о запятой, которая находится в другой части предложения, где две **пары** _на морях и на суше_ + _в походах и дома_, о которых говорится в п.9. В этих парах уже два союза, который ещё раз повторяется для их соединения.

Comment: Спасибо большое за объяснение! Теперь понятно.

Answer (score 1):

1) А мне вот далеко не всё непонятно, и я полагаю, что пример у Розенталя не по заявленной теме. **Вот один из его печатных вариантов:**

И нагнулся старый атаман и стал отыскивать в траве свою люльку с табаком, неотлучную сопутницу **(1) на морях и на суше, и (2) в походах, и (3) дома.**

https://ilibrary.ru/text/1070/p.14/index.html

Здесь запятые поставлены, так как союз И повторяется два раза.

2) **У Розенталя  по его теме правильны два других примера:** Среди рек есть и (1) большие и малые, и (2) спокойные и буйные, и (3) быстрые и медленные; Снаряды рвались и (1) близко и далеко, и (2) справа и слева.

3) **А в примере  из Гоголя нет первой запятой:** И нагнулся старый атаман, и стал отыскивать свою люльку с табаком, неотлучную спутницу **(1) на морях и на суше, и (2) в походах и дома (Г.);**

**Из-за этой неопределенности в Сети появляются разные варианты**, например: Нагнулся старый атаман и стал отыскивать в траве свою люльку с табаком, неотлучную спутницу **на морях, и на суше, и в походах, и дома.**

4) Но вот что интересно: если ориентироваться на интонацию, но лучшим вариантом является тот, который приведен у Розенталя: И нагнулся старый атаман, и стал отыскивать свою люльку с табаком, неотлучную спутницу **(1) на морях и на суше,  (2) и в походах и дома (Г.);**

Здесь **сближенные по значению пары явно просматриваются** и между ними сделана пауза, обозначенная запятой. А объяснение такое:  **"и в походах и дома" нужно считать   единой конструкцией.**

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Редакция 1842 года

И нагнулся старый атаман и стал отыскивать в траве свою люльку с табаком, неотлучную сопутницу на морях, и на суше, и в походах, и дома.

Comment: "Первой" запятой нет _ни в одном_ печатном издании (думаю, что начальное  "И" отнесено ко всему предложению), но "вторая" запятая есть в очень многих, сравнительно поздних (примерно с 80-х годов) изданиях. Без проблемной запятой мне встретились издания 37-го и 70-го годов. Предположительно, она возникла позже и стала копироваться. Розенталь в _нескольких_ своих книгах приводит этот пример без запятой, т. е. настаивает. В процитированном справочнике это вполне по теме пункта 9.

Comment: А где в п. 9 первый союз И, чтобы было: и на морях и на суше, и в походах и дома (Г.); Сравнить: и близко и далеко, и  справа и слева..Удивительное дело, даже прочитать и нормально напечатать Гоголя не могут. Проблемные запятые откуда-то появляются, классика начинают править каждый на свой лад.

Comment: А зачем первый союз? Здесь два союза внутри пар и третий, который соединяет пары; запятая - на своём основании, сформулированном перед первой группой примеров. Любопытно было бы увидеть скан прижизненного издания (в 52 году лишние запятые уже были), чтобы понять, позиция это лично Розенталя или так было и исторически.

Comment: Всё замечательно, но по вашим описаниям ничего нельзя понять. Нужно предложение, где цифрами обозначены все запятые, о которых Вы говорите, и союзы И, которых всего пять: союз (1), союз (2) и т.д. Может быть, Вам всё ясно, но судя по количеству экспериментов с запятыми, ясно далеко не всем. Меня в первую очередь интересовал бы авторский вариант, а не то, как Розенталь объяснял его.

Comment: В вопросе фигурирует одна запятая, указанная однозначно. Цитата там с такой же пунктуацией, как у Розенталя (в справочнике, в пособии "Говорите и пишите по-русски правильно", в Справочнике по лит. правке и др.). Поэтому меня поняли. Варианты с другими запятыми в моём ответе не возникали.

Comment: Ну да, все поняли, кроме тех, кто в Сети ставит разное количество запятых (одну, две, три).

Comment: История возникновения дополнительных запятых заслуживает отдельного исследования (они реально присутствуют во многих печатных изданиях, вчера дома посмотрел в шеститомнике 52-го года), но оно затруднено тем, что гугл не показывает целиком отсканированные страницы (будто совсем перестал - выглядит как новая политика; показываются только строки с номером страницы).

Comment: Ваша позиция по этому вопросу кажется мне правильной, но позвольте задать вопрос. Если руководствоваться правилами Розенталя и других товарищей, то мы в предложении "Они все стали примерять туфли, босоножки, кофточки и куртки." можем туфли и босоножки объединить в первую пару, а кофточки и куртки - во вторую. Получится, мы можем соединить эти однородные пары однородных членов с помощью союза "и" иполучить "Они все стали примерять туфли и босонижки и кофточки и куртки." Это ведь правильно? Если можно объединять их с использованием повторяющихся союзов, то можно с не повторяющимся.